# talk app on galaxy s3 crashes @ 240 DPI

Tags: android

This bug is just killing me for past one month.

I'm using galaxy s3  running stock jelly bean rom which has a 320 DPI by default. I always change my DPI to 240 as 320 DPI looks too big. I never had any problem in the past with 240 DPI.(Even all aosp rom's talk app runs fine @ 240 DPI). But with stock roms the talk app simply crashes whenever an alert is received and the error message is:

```
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): FATAL EXCEPTION: Packet Processor
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@429611d0
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1026)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1096)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:466)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.service.StatusBarNotifier.getAvatarForContact(StatusBarNotifier.java:726)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.service.StatusBarNotifier$NotificationInfo$Item.<init>(StatusBarNotifier.java:105)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.service.StatusBarNotifier$NotificationInfo.add(StatusBarNotifier.java:160)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.service.StatusBarNotifier.notify(StatusBarNotifier.java:415)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.service.StatusBarNotifier.notifyChat(StatusBarNotifier.java:314)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.gtalk.ChatSession.notifyChat(ChatSession.java:2237)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.gtalk.ChatSession.onReceiveMessage(ChatSession.java:905)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.gtalk.ChatMgr.processIncomingMessage(ChatMgr.java:869)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.gtalk.ChatMgr.processPacket(ChatMgr.java:642)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketProcessor.process(PacketProcessor.java:122)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketProcessor.access$000(PacketProcessor.java:13)
10-16 21:56:59.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14559):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketProcessor$1.run(PacketProcessor.java:45)
10-16 21:56:59.875: E/android.os.Debug(2733): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an optimized for the API Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, boolean filter).

consider this situation:

1. the scaledWidth equal to the sourceBitmap's width
2. the scaledHeight equal to the sourceBitmap's height

this API will return the same bitmap object instance as the sourceBitmap under JellyBean, but a different bitmap object instance under ICS and below (gingerbread ......). I have tested this issue under JellyBean and ICS.

So if your code recycle the returned bitmap under the given situation, the sourceBitmap will be recycled too. Actually maybe you used the sourceBitmap to draw on the canvas,  but the sourceBitmap is recycled, so your app is crashed under JellyBean.

To fix this issue, your should check the scaledWidth and scaledHeight parameter with sourceBitmap before use the API Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(.....) see the code below:

```
    public Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap,  int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, boolean filter){
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    if (null != sourceBitmap){
        if(sourceBitmap.getWidth() == scaledWidth && sourceBitmap.getHeight() == scaledHeight){
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap);
        }else{
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, filter);
        }
    }

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hi there,i actually managed to solve this issue after having a tear down on framewor-res.apk                                         <blockquote><dimen name="notification_large_icon_width">55.0dip</dimen>
><dimen name="notification_large_icon_height">64.0dip</dimen>>

Comment: Actually this bug is caused by call Bitamp.recycle() mathod on a UI used bitmap. However, some bug is only occured on Android 4.1 and above. The reason please refer above answer.